# How Can I optimize my query with union all and dense rank?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, query-performance

That query is taking 3' (selecting on non-indexed views) to execute and I would like to know if you guys know what can be optimized ?

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        *,          
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cmd.OrderYear, cmd.OrderSequence) R2
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            Project1.*
         FROM 
         ( 
            SELECT Extent1.*
                FROM  
                    [WS].[viewOrderDetail] AS [Extent1]  
                WHERE 
                    [Extent1].CustomerID IN (2,7,8,9)    
           )  AS [Project1]
    ) AS [Cmd]  
    LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrders] AS [orders] ON ([orders].Year=[cmd].OrderYear AND [orders].[Sequence]=[cmd].OrderSequence)
    LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrderLines] AS [OrderLines] ON ([OrderLines].[OrderYear] = [Cmd].[OrderYear] AND OrderLines.OrderSequence = Cmd.OrderSequence )
    LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrderLineSupplements] AS [Supp]  ON (Supp.OrderYear = OrderLines.OrderYear AND Supp.OrderSequence = OrderLines.OrderSequence AND Supp.OrderLineSequence= OrderLines.Sequence)
    WHERE CAST(Cmd.OrderYear as varchar(3)) +'.'+ right('000000' + CAST(Cmd.OrderSequence as varchar(6)),6) LIKE '%11301%'
) a
WHERE R2 >= (1 + 0) AND R2 < (1 + 20)

union all

SELECT 
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        *,                                          
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cmd.OrderYear, cmd.OrderSequence) R2
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            Project1.*
         FROM 
         ( 
            SELECT Extent1.*
                FROM  
                    [WS].[viewOrderDetail] AS [Extent1]  
                WHERE 
                    [Extent1].CustomerID IN (2,7,8,9)    
           )  AS [Project1]
    ) AS [Cmd]  
    LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrders] AS [orders] ON ([orders].Year=[cmd].OrderYear AND [orders].[Sequence]=[cmd].OrderSequence)
    LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrderLines] AS [OrderLines] ON ([OrderLines].[OrderYear] = [Cmd].[OrderYear] AND OrderLines.OrderSequence = Cmd.OrderSequence )
    LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrderLineSupplements] AS [Supp]  ON (Supp.OrderYear = OrderLines.OrderYear AND Supp.OrderSequence = OrderLines.OrderSequence AND Supp.OrderLineSequence= OrderLines.Sequence)
    WHERE Orders.Reference LIKE '%11301%'
) a
WHERE R2 >= (1 + 0) AND R2 < (1 + 20)


union all

SELECT 
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        *,                                              
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cmd.OrderYear, cmd.OrderSequence) R2
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            Project1.*
         FROM 
         ( 
            SELECT Extent1.*
                FROM  
                    [WS].[viewOrderDetail] AS [Extent1]  
                WHERE 
                    [Extent1].CustomerID IN (2,7,8,9)    
           )  AS [Project1]
    ) AS [Cmd]  
    LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrders] AS [orders] ON ([orders].Year=[cmd].OrderYear AND [orders].[Sequence]=[cmd].OrderSequence)
    LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrderLines] AS [OrderLines] ON ([OrderLines].[OrderYear] = [Cmd].[OrderYear] AND OrderLines.OrderSequence = Cmd.OrderSequence )
    LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrderLineSupplements] AS [Supp]  ON (Supp.OrderYear = OrderLines.OrderYear AND Supp.OrderSequence = OrderLines.OrderSequence AND Supp.OrderLineSequence= OrderLines.Sequence)
    WHERE OrderLines.Reference LIKE '%11301%'
) a
WHERE R2 >= (1 + 0) AND R2 < (1 + 20)


union all


SELECT 
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        *,                                          
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cmd.OrderYear, cmd.OrderSequence) R2
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            Project1.*
         FROM 
         ( 
            SELECT Extent1.*
                FROM  
                    [WS].[viewOrderDetail] AS [Extent1]  
                WHERE 
                    [Extent1].CustomerID IN (2,7,8,9)    
           )  AS [Project1]
    ) AS [Cmd]  
    LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrders] AS [orders] ON ([orders].Year=[cmd].OrderYear AND [orders].[Sequence]=[cmd].OrderSequence)
    LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrderLines] AS [OrderLines] ON ([OrderLines].[OrderYear] = [Cmd].[OrderYear] AND OrderLines.OrderSequence = Cmd.OrderSequence )
    LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrderLineSupplements] AS [Supp]  ON (Supp.OrderYear = OrderLines.OrderYear AND Supp.OrderSequence = OrderLines.OrderSequence AND Supp.OrderLineSequence= OrderLines.Sequence)
    WHERE CAST(OrderLines.OrderYear as varchar(4)) +'.'+ right('000000' + CAST(OrderLines.OrderSequence as varchar(6)),6)+'.'+right('000'+cast(OrderLines.Sequence as varchar(3)),3) LIKE '%11301%'    
) a
WHERE R2 >= (1 + 0) AND R2 < (1 + 20)
ORDER BY a.DeliveryDate DESC
```

I really need to reduce the time of execution of that query. Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you had a look at the execution plan to find out about the most time-consuming parts? And I'm not sure about the `SELECT [Project1].*` sub queries. Do they actually add anything to the query?

Comment: Have a look at query execution plan it will gives you the details

Comment: You're right, these subqueries are useless, thanks ! I cannot look at the execution plan to find out about the most time-consuming parts since the query only take a lot of time to execute on production database (I don't have any access on it)

Comment: This makes it of course a lot harder then. It seems like your "base queries" (the ones with the `LEFT JOIN`s) are all alike except for the `WHERE` part. If that's the case it might be a good idea to load all this data into a table variable or a temporary table first and then do the filtering there. That way you only had to read the view data once, I think.

Comment: you can try estimated exectuion plan instead of actual exectuion plan it will be helpful

Comment: All those subqueries do a `select *`. Is getting all the columns of those 4 tables really neccesairy?  Just selecting the columns that it really needs would already make it less heavy.

Comment: I do select only the columns I need, but I removed them to make the query more clear

Comment: Adding the [Cmd] subquery in a WITH at the start will make it possible to reuse the resultset in the unioned queries.

Comment: move the common dataset in to one  temp table  and then try querying from that table eg:SELECT Extent1.*
                FROM  
                    [WS].[viewOrderDetail] AS [Extent1]  
                WHERE 
                    [Extent1].CustomerID IN (2,7,8,9) this is common in all datasets so that it will not hit the main table which is having large data three times

Comment: The result of the SELECT Extent1.* contains MILLIONS of results. I Do neeed the WHERE clause to filter

Comment: SELECT Extent1.* into #temp  FROM [WS].[viewOrderDetail] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].CustomerID IN (2,7,8,9) .use this #temp in all select statements instead of retrieving from main table so that it will not select million records three times instead it will select the filtered record from temp table

Comment: I'll try that, thanks @Mani

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query.. I just modified your query,couldn't test it,since i don't have the detailed schema information.

```
;WITH cte_1
AS
(SELECT Extent1.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].OrderYear
        ,[Extent1].OrderSequence) R2
 FROM   [WS].[viewOrderDetail] AS [Extent1]  
 WHERE  [Extent1].CustomerID IN (2,7,8,9) 
    AND CAST([Extent1].OrderYear as varchar(3)) +'.'+ right('000000' + CAST([Extent1].OrderSequence as varchar(6)),6) LIKE '%11301%')  

, cte_2
 AS
  (SELECT Extent1.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].OrderYear
         , [Extent1].OrderSequence) R2
   FROM   [WS].[viewOrderDetail] AS [Extent1]  
     LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrders] AS [orders] 
        ON ([orders].Year=[Extent1].OrderYear AND [orders].[Sequence]=[Extent1].OrderSequence)
  WHERE  [Extent1].CustomerID IN (2,7,8,9) 
    AND Orders.Reference LIKE '%11301%')   

, cte_3
  AS
  (SELECT Extent1.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].OrderYear
         , [Extent1].OrderSequence) R2
   FROM   [WS].[viewOrderDetail] AS [Extent1]  
     LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrders] AS [orders] 
        ON ([orders].Year=[Extent1].OrderYear AND [orders].[Sequence]=[Extent1].OrderSequence)
      LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrderLines] AS [OrderLines] 
        ON ([OrderLines].[OrderYear] = [Extent1].[OrderYear] AND OrderLines.OrderSequence = [Extent1].OrderSequence )
  WHERE  [Extent1].CustomerID IN (2,7,8,9) 
           AND OrderLines.Reference LIKE '%11301%')
, cte_4
AS
  (SELECT Extent1.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].OrderYear
          , [Extent1].OrderSequence) R2
   FROM   [WS].[viewOrderDetail] AS [Extent1]  
      LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrders] AS [orders] 
        ON ([orders].Year=[Extent1].OrderYear AND [orders].[Sequence]=[Extent1].OrderSequence)
      LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrderLines] AS [OrderLines] 
        ON ([OrderLines].[OrderYear] = [Extent1].[OrderYear] AND OrderLines.OrderSequence = [Extent1].OrderSequence )
      LEFT JOIN [WS].[viewOrderLineSupplements] AS [Supp]  
        ON (Supp.OrderYear = OrderLines.OrderYear AND Supp.OrderSequence = OrderLines.OrderSequence AND Supp.OrderLineSequence= OrderLines.Sequence)
  WHERE  [Extent1].CustomerID IN (2,7,8,9) 
    AND CAST(OrderLines.OrderYear as varchar(4)) +'.'+ right('000000' + CAST(OrderLines.OrderSequence as varchar(6)),6)+'.'+right('000'+cast(OrderLines.Sequence as varchar(3)),3) LIKE '%11301%')    

SELECT  *
FROM cte_1 a
WHERE a.R2 >= (1 + 0) AND a.R2 < (1 + 20)
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM cte_2 a
WHERE a.R2 >= (1 + 0) AND a.R2 < (1 + 20)
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM cte_3 a
WHERE a.R2 >= (1 + 0) AND a.R2 < (1 + 20)
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM cte_4 a
WHERE a.R2 >= (1 + 0) AND a.R2 < (1 + 20)
ORDER BY a.DeliveryDate DESC
```

Comment: I need the join on each query, it's just not for filtering (I need their columns too)

Comment: as per your script you are getting data from the table ViewOrderDetail based on based on different criteria from the four sub queries.. The same we can do with cte..